# SQLite: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range. The statement has 0 parameters

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting the following error, and I have no idea why it is occurring. I was wondering if anyone else might be able to shed some light on the issue.

```
12-25 22:52:50.252: E/AndroidRuntime(813): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
12-25 22:52:50.252: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
12-25 22:52:50.252: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)
12-25 22:52:50.252: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
12-25 22:52:50.252: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
12-25 22:52:50.252: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
12-25 22:52:50.252: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
12-25 22:52:50.252: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
12-25 22:52:50.252: E/AndroidRuntime(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
```

The code is here:

```
public Player getPlayer(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {
            PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_NAME,
            PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYED_GAMES,
            };

    String selection =  PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_NAME ;
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[1];
    selectionArgs[0] = name;

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            PlayerEntry.TABLE_NAME,  // The table to query
            projection,                               // The columns to return
            selection,                                // The columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,                            // The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                                     // don't group the rows
            null,                                     // don't filter by row groups
            null                                 // The sort order
            );

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: From what I've read on `query` method, it seems that `selection` is not a column name, but a full WHERE clause possibly containing `?` references to `selectionArgs`. That is, `selection` should be like `"PlayerName=?"`, with `selectionArgs` being a list of one value (as in your code).

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The `selection` should be an expression and `selectionArgs` should have as many elements as there are `?` literal placeholders in `selection`.

Your `selection` is not an expression and does not have any `?` but you have one element in `selectionArgs`.

You probably want something like:

```
String selection =  PlayerEntry.COLUMN_NAME_PLAYER_NAME + "=?";
```

to make it an expression that matches the player name column agains the literal you're binding in `selectionArgs[0]`.

Comment: In my case I had the question mark inside single quotes like this `'?'`.  Removing the single quotes resolved the error.

Comment: @mattblang I think it would be a good idea to add your comment to a new answer so it could help more people who ran in to this just like me. Feel like giving it a try?

Comment: @theblang same problem killing quite some time... Hey, what if we need the quotes around a bound prepared variable? For example, when you are matching against a string?

Answer (score 3):

> In my case I had the question mark inside single quotes like this '?'. Removing the single quotes resolved the error.

Copied from theblang's comment above.