# Error With Cursor When Loading Details From Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm currently working through a school project, trying to create a Scout Group manager.  This is my first time using Java, XML or Android Studio, so progress has been a little slow, but I'm getting there.  The issue I'm having at the moment is with extracting Scout details from a database, in order for them to be placed in a spinner.  The leader will then select the Scouts they want to invite, by name, from the spinner.  The code which is apparently causing the error (in the database handler class) is below:

```
public Cursor GetAllScouts()
{
    String whereClause = COLUMN_SECTION + "=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{"Beavers","Cubs","Scouts","Explorers","Network","Leaders"};
    String[] columns = new String[]{COLUMN_SCID + " AS " + BaseColumns._ID, COLUMN_FNAME, COLUMN_LNAME, COLUMN_SECTION};
    return db.query(TABLE_SCOUTS,columns,whereClause,whereArgs,null,null,null);//Error is being thrown up here
}
```

And the information from the logcat is below again:

```
01-24 18:39:38.228 18179-18179/com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype, PID: 18179
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype/com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype.frmCreateEvent2}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 6 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 6 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 1 parameters.
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
    at com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype.databaseHandler.GetAllScouts(databaseHandler.java:395)
    at com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype.frmCreateEvent2.loadSpinnerData(frmCreateEvent2.java:87)
    at com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype.frmCreateEvent2.onCreate(frmCreateEvent2.java:82)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20777605/10928836). Your  selection (where clause) must contain exactly as many `?` as arguments are given in your selection arguments. In this case your selection only contains one `?` but you give 6 selection arguments.

The selection you probably want is:

```
COLUMN_SECTION + "IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Passing your list of section as the selectionArgs should work then.

Consider checking out [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#java) to learn more about saving data with SQLite.

Comment: This completely solved the database issue - unfortunately, it turns out there's still an issue with the spinner.  Thanks for all your help on the SQL though, it worked absolutely fine after this!

Comment: How are you implementing the Spinner? What have you tried? Please update your question so we have more information.

Comment: I worked out the problem - sorry, I thought best not to put it here as I felt it was entirely different to the question I had initially asked.  Thank you for your help with the database stuff, though.

Comment: Alright, good to hear that you could work it out on your own. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `whereClause = COLUMN_SECTION + "=?";` has a single argument. But you are passing 6 selection arguments in `whereArgs = new String[]{"Beavers","Cubs","Scouts","Explorers","Network","Leaders"};`.

That is precisely what the error is suggesting. It expects single whereArgument.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that!  Those selections are actually all the Sections in Scouting - could you advise me of the correct way to select all Scouts of all different sections for use in a spinner, using a cursor?  Thanks!

Comment: You just need to change your where clause to look like this -  
`whereClause = COLUMN_SECTION + " IN " + ('Beavers','Cubs','Scouts','Explorers','Network', 'Leaders')`

To make this we can have -
`"whereClause = COLUMN_SECTION + " IN  " +  
 " ( ?  , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ) "`

and keep the whereArgs same.

Comment: This is correct as well sorry, I just can't mark both as right.  Upvoted it though.  Thanks for pointing this out though!

Answer (score 0):

Does the list need to be mutable? If not, you can just specify a string array in your `strings.xml` file in your resources, like so:

**strings.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array
        name="scout_categories">
        <item>Beavers</item>
        <item>Cubs</item>
        <item>Scouts</item>
        <item>Explorers</item>
        <item>Network</item>
        <item>Leaders</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then, wherever you're setting up your `Spinner` object:

**SomeActivity.java**

```java
Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

String[] scoutCategories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.scout_categories);        

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_layout, R.id.text, countries);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

*See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[])) for using the `ArrayAdapter`

Now, if it DOES need to be a mutable list, then I suggest looking into [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) for Android. It is way easier to get a DB up and running and takes care of a lot of the boilerplate code for you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I was entirely clear in my question - I'll go back and edit it.  I'm trying to load Scout names from a database in order for the leader to be able to invite them to events.  What you've put down there should be helpful for another part of the program though - thanks!

Comment: @SamOg ah I see what you're meaning now. The other answers here should fix your issue then :)

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway!